# CallerMemberName equivalence in netstandard

Tags: c#, .net-standard

In .NET Framework, a function can get the method/file/line number of the caller by attributes [CallerFilePath], [CallerMemberName], [CallerLineNumber]. In netstandard this is not supported. What would be the equivalence to this? Is there a way to do this?

I would be nice of the function can grab the caller data without the caller have to pass them directly, like how I was able to do it with the attributes.

Comment: It seems that currently netstandard supports these attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use class [StackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx). It allows you to trace information about the execution as a list of Frames. `Frame 0` is your current element, so you target frame index is 1, if it is there ofcourse e.g.

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
var frame = st.GetFrame(1);
var method = frame.GetMethod();
var file = frame.GetFileName();
var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
```

Check other methods of that class

Comment: As this is evaluated during runtime and we need stack frame access, keep in mind that this is much more expensive compared to the attributes!